# $_session in if statement slows down extract($row)

Tags: php

I'm noticing a huge slow down when i try to autofill a dropdown menu with an selected value based on a $_SESSION value. The dropdown contains around 250 values:

```
$query = "SELECT
          pm_id,
          pm_name
          FROM products_materials
          ORDER BY pm_name";

          $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
          $stmt->execute();
```

I got the following code to get the rows:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      extract($row);
                                
          if ($pm_id == $_SESSION['pu_pm_id']) {
             echo "<option selected value='{$pm_id}'>{$pm_name}</option>";
          } else {
             echo "<option value='{$pm_id}'>{$pm_name}</option>";
          }
}
```

This code runs in 2000ms while the following code runs in under 300ms:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
       echo "<option value='{$pm_id}'>{$pm_name}</option>";
}
```

What can I do to improve the load time?

Comment: I really doubt that it is the loop itself that takes such different amounts of time - and I also doubt whether you _actually_ measured that?

Comment: How are you storing your sessions, and which library/extension are you using to store session data?

Comment: The session is stored server side, it's default php 5 setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to extract value from session before loop:

```
$sessionID = $_SESSION['pu_pm_id'];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
                            
    if ($pm_id == $sessionID) {
        echo "<option selected value='{$pm_id}'>{$pm_name}</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='{$pm_id}'>{$pm_name}</option>";
    }
}
```

So you don't have to access session every time inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! It reduced the loading time to 400ms.

Comment: Can you please explain why would that make such a huge difference? I don't think this is possible

Comment: @Dharman That really depends on what else he has in his session, and on speed of server itself. Because a session is stored in a file on server, it could take a lot of time to get to proper value. And if he has tons of records in his loop, it adds up real quick.